# mysql subquery in single table

Tags: select, mysql, join, subquery

I have 2 columns in an "entries" table: a non-unique id, and a date stamp (YYYY-MM-DD). I want to select "all of the entry id's that were inserted today that have never been entered before."

I've been trying to use a subquery, but I don't think I'm using it right since they're both performed on the same table. Could someone help me out with the proper select statement? I can provide more details if need be.

Comment: You should note your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have access to a mysql database right now, but this should help:

```
select
  e.id
from
   entries e
where
   e.date = curdate() and
   e.id not in
     (select id from entries e2 where e2.date < e.date)
```